# how to make classic Resume to reflect everything

Tags: resume, software-industry, career-development

Well i don't know is this right place to ask or not but i wanted to know how can i make resume show everything, done even a bit task also.

As we don't have proofs every time for what we have done,sometimes we have knowledge but no project in that area.or experience.

Eg:  a computer engineer can be of any field Either **Networking** , Either **Software** ,or **hardware** also for a basic engineer ,if he has done mastery in software field he might have also gained knowledge in **hardware** also but he don't have proof for that, also in **software** field a computer engineer can be a **designer** or a **programmer** or any other .but sometimes it shows negative impact to show that the person is good at both **designing** and **programming**

So how can an effective resume be written so that it reflects everything in every area.with proper highlights.

thanks .

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much..." ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: yeah i know,i m asking too much but thats all i wanted to know :(

Comment: Downvoter please comment for downvotes.Do you think its not a good question or somebody can't have questions like this please do suggest me where should i go to ask  where i don't get negative votes for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, an effective resume does 2 things:

- Gets past the software screen by utilizing the keywords that the company is looking for. Typically they list these on the job posting. If your posting to a site like Dice than use Google AdWords to get as many of the different keywords in the resume as possible for the position you want.
- Gets you in front of (or on the phone with) a hiring manager at the company. I find that a lot of hiring managers hear a lot about what a person can do. List what you **HAVE** done. On my LinkedIn profile (as an example), I put verbatim "I am a huge fan of knowledge in general. That being said, actions speak louder than words. I post the majority of my larger projects that I work on here."

In summary, include the keywords in a creative way that gets you past the software without being obvious that was your intentions. Use your actual experiences to reinforce the fact that you not only know something but, more importantly, know how to implement it. The point of the resume is not to get you the job but to get you the interview.

Also leave some things for the interview to shock and awe the potential employer. Something that will make you stand above and beyond the people that were interviewed for that position that they would not have expected when inviting you to the interview. This keeps you on their mind during the hiring process.

This is just my experience, I am sure there is far better answers but I have been rather successful at getting jobs even though I am horrible at interviewing.

Comment: yeah i liked the way you said ,but tell me PaulDonny would it be not negative for the interviewer that the person knows about so many fields ,that can simply show that person is not focused towards one thing,like in my case i know designing and programming both.so would it be ?

Comment: Well, the issue then becomes why are you going after x position and not y position. For example, I am in QA. I have experiences that would be better suited for the roles of PM,BA,SA or Developer (if your unfamiliar with these roles, they are typically considered higher level more prestigious roles). When asked why I am in QA with these qualifications, it's because I am passionate about and love my position. If you have a good, honest reason why you are going after x with the experience of y, than list it. If the reason is because 'Its easier' leave it off.

Comment: thanks @PaulDonny i got you point ,exactly what i wanted  (y).

Answer (score 2):

An effective resume will highlight what the hiring manager is looking for, in the 30 seconds they use to glance over it.  It must quickly catch their eye that you are a potential person to interview.

So your resume should NOT be a wall of text, including everything that you've done.  It should have easy to read bullet points that quickly show your relevent experience for that particular job, appropriate accomplishments and benefits you've provided to your current and previous employers, and appropriate education.  It should not be gimmicky, but be clean and clear.

The purpose of the cover letter and resume is to get the interview.  You can go into more depth in the interview.

Comment: how to mention as you said.."accomplishments and benefits you've provided to your current and previous employers, and appropriate education."